# Extract values from a list and put them into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have data in a list (numbers, numbers).
I want to subtract the trailing number from this data and put it in a dataframe.
The number before the comma in the list is equal to the index of the dataframe.

--------------Below is a code example. -------------

```
import pandas as pd

test_list=[(1,124),(2,234),(3,344)]
test_data={
    'index' : [1,2,3],
    'data1' : [3,5,6],
    'data2' : [2,5,6]
}


test_df  =pd.DataFrame(test_data)
test_df
```

---

**Example Image**

[image]

I want to add test_list to the last column of test_df.
As an example, I made a small list and data frame with some examples.
Can I put it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataframe out of `test_list`, and merge it to the `test_df`

```py
>>> test_df.merge(pd.DataFrame(test_list, columns=['index', 'number']))

   index  data1  data2  number
0      1      3      2     124
1      2      5      5     234
2      3      6      6     344
```

Another option is to use dictionary instead of list  of tuples, then use `pandas.Series.map` to map the values:

```py
>>> test_d = {1: 124, 2: 234, 3: 344}
>>> test_df['number']=test_df['index'].map(test_d)
>>> test_df
   index  data1  data2  number
0      1      3      2     124
1      2      5      5     234
2      3      6      6     344
```